# How to optionally set a value for custom HTML property? (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, binding

Just recently started learning Angular 2 and so far really enjoying it. All this binding back and forth is really powerful and is opening a whole new world for me.

I'm at a bit of a standstill, though, trying to figure out how to set values on HTML element properties.

I use [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) for styling and it has some pretty form validation messages that can be shown to the user.

The problem is those messages are passed as values via `data-error` and `data-success` properties on the `label` tag for a particular field:

```
<div class="input-field inline">
    <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
    <label for="email" data-error="Invalid email address." data-success="Valid email address.">Email</label>
</div>
```

I've already fallen in love with tools like `NgClass`

```
[class.valid]="myForm.controls['name'].valid && myForm.controls['name'].touched"
```

So there I can conditionally add `valid` to the `class` attribute. Which gets me halfway there.

I also know that I can add properties and set value for properties with something like this:

`[attr.data-error]="nameErrMsg"`

So I tried writing a function to dynamically set the validation message depending on the state of any errors reported:

```
nameErrMsg(): string {
  let message = '';

  if(this.myForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required') && this.myForm.controls['firstName'].touched) {
    message = "Name is required."
  } else if (this.myForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('minlength') && this.myForm.controls['firstName'].touched) {
    message = "Name must have at least 5 characters."
  }

  return message;
}
```

But apparently that just gives me the whole function back as the error message...

[image]

Any advice on how I should proceed with dynamically setting the `data-error` property value?

The function above works if I just log the message, but how do I get it passed and set as the value of `data-error` (e.g. `data-error="Name is required."`)?

Comment: I think you're missing the parentheses. You're not actually calling the function. So it should be `[attr.data-error]="nameErrMsg()"`

Comment: I'd be interested to know if Matthew's suggestion works. Out of curiosity, if you weren't using Angular and had hard-coded `data-error` attributes, who would be displaying those messages? MaterializeCSS itself? (kind of looks like you're implementing form validation twice)

Comment: @MatthewAllen I promise I'm not a complete idiot...just mostly one. Yes, that absolutely did the trick - thank you for pointing it out! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @AngularFrance per my comment above Matthew's suggestion did the trick. Great question - if I hard coded the `data-error` attribute (and even in this case where I apply the `data-error` attribute dynamically) it is MaterializeCSS that displays the messages. When a field has the CSS class `valid` Materialize makes the field green and shows the message you specify in `data-success` and if it has the class `invalid` it displays the message you specify in `data-error`. I wanted unique `data-error` messages depending on which validation was being violated, hence the need for applying it dynamically

Comment: @BrockKlein. Interesting. So there's a slight overlap between what Angular and MaterializeCSS can do as far as form validation.

Comment: @AngularFrance yes, definitely. I think my implementation successfully decouples the logic from the visual, keeping the logic in Angular and the visual with Materialize.